# How would I convert percentages into hours, on tasks spent on an 8 hour work day?

Tags: equivalence-relations

How would I convert percentages into an 8 hour day?  for example if I worked 17% of my 8 hour work day on one task and 14% of my 8 hour work day on another task how would I convert these into hours or minutes spent on each task? I have multiple tasks that equal 100% of an 8 hour work day I need to know how to convert percentages to hours. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To take a percentage of a quantity, you multiply the percentage times that quantity. So, for example, $17\%$ of $8 \ \mathrm{hr}$ is

$$ \left( 17\% \right) \left( 8 \ \mathrm{hr} \right) = \left( 0.17 \right) \left( 8 \ \mathrm{hr} \right) = 1.36 \ \mathrm{hr}$$

Remember, *per cent* literally translates to “per hundred,” and the symbol $\%$ simply stands in for $\div100$.

Can you take the rest from here?

Comment: Got it :) Thank You soooo much!!!

Comment: @SandyM If you feel it helped, consider giving it an upvote and/or the green check.